# PySpark: DataFrame to LibSVM format

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "'a':1 'b':2"), (0, "'b':1")], ["label", "features"])
```

How to turn `DataFrame` to `LibSVM` format and get the mapping relationship between the index and feature name.

Expected LibSVM format:

```
1 1:1 2:2
0 2:1
```

Mapping relationship between index and original feature name:

```
1  a
2  b
```

Comment: Have you found it out in the meanwhile?